# To modify a line that match start and mid part of a text in a line inplace

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I have a file say Abc.txt . It consist of many lines.
I want to use sed or may be any other command that modifies that line in place in that file.
Suppose line has just one word like below

```
ABCDsdfg01klmn
```

Here I check if line starts with ABC and then check if it also has 00 and in that case I want to modify 01 by say PM . How can i do it ?

I want to add some further specific . I want it to be done only for lines that have say 4 character between ABCD and 01 . I dont want to modify it for lines say that has 3 characters or 5 characters between ABCD and 01 e.g `ABCDsfg01klmn` or `ABCDsdfgh01klmn`

```
ABCDsdfgPMklmn
```

Comment: `ABCD03020101klmn` has 4 characters (`0302`) between `ABCD` and the start of `0101` - would you want that to match your regexp?

Comment: Whats with  `ABCD010101...`? Is it a match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
sed -r 's/^(ABCD.{4})01/\1PM/' file
```

If a line contains `ABC` plus 4 characters and a 01 the `s` command is used to replace `01` by `PM`.

Comment: Edited my Question further . Sorry for incomplete one earlier.

Comment: i think it would be `sed -r '/ABC.{5}01/s/01/PM/' file`

Comment: As per your comment to the question, that may produce `ABCPM0101...` -- you may want `sed 's/^\(ABC....\)01/\1PM/'`

Comment: @glennjackman while that command is simpler, doesn't it produce the same output?

Comment: With the proviso that the OP wants to match just `^ABC` (no D), the answer is no. Yours replaces the **first** "01" in the line no matter where it occurs in the string; mine replaces the one after the four "spacing" characters.

Comment: Oh yes, I see! Later in the text OP states that he expects 4 characters between `ABCD` and the `01` - makes the question unclear about `ABC` or `ABCD` should be the start pattern. However your comment still applies, will change that